# what is the correct format of xml to import into SQL Inject Me?

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, firefox-addon

I have been googling around the FAQ and documentation of SQL Inject Me but I couldn't find anything about the correct format of XML document to import SQL Injections to this Firefox add on.

So, I checked the source code [here](https://github.com/SecurityCompass/SQL-Inject-Me) to get an idea, but unfortunately my JavaScript is not so good and I couldn't understand much.

I have tried the same format as their export provides:

`<attacks><attack><attackString><![CDATA[1 OR 1=1]]></attackString>
      <signature>ha.ckers.org SQL Injection Cheet Sheet</signature></attack></attacks>`

But I still get parsing error. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: For reference: the import code starts [here](https://github.com/SecurityCompass/SQL-Inject-Me/blob/master/content/preferences.fx3.js#L174). From the look of it, your XML code should work fine.

Comment: @WladimirPalantᛜ I have even tried: 

<attacks><attack><attackString>1 OR 1=1</attackString> <signature>ha.ckers.org SQL Injection Cheet Sheet</signature></attack></attacks>

but I get the same error:"error while parsing document, ensure that the document is complete and uncorrupted."

Comment: When you save the xml file, do you explicitly set the encoding or let the editor use some default? Try to save it as iso-latin-1 or ansi.

Comment: @paa thanks a lot! it works now with ANSI encoding, I had saved it with editor's default.